# WaitForSingleObject With timeout=0

Tags: multithreading, winapi, visual-c++, mutex

I have a mutex created in non signaled state

```
HANDLE hmutex= CreateMutex(NULL,FALSE,"");---1
```

Now I am calling

```
DWORD dw = WaitForSingleObject(hmutex,0); ---2
```

Since hmutex is not signaled, WaitForSingleObject will return immediately but will state of hmutex will change to signaled??

If another thread calls this second statement what will happen?

Comment: You are creating a named mutex with an empty name. Is this intentional?

Comment: yes , its intentional

Comment: Don't do that (use an empty name), it's begging for a collision.  If you don't want a name, pass NULL and receive an unnamed mutex.

Comment: @Ben: Thanks for advice , will take care of that

Answer (score 6):

No, it won't change to signaled.

The following invariants are true about that call:

- It returns immediately regardless of the mutex state.
- The mutex becomes owned (non-signaled) regardless of its previous state.
- The return value tells you whether you gained ownership or failed due to contention.

In all cases, someone owns the mutex.  However, if another thread was owner, it could release the mutex at any time, so by the time the function returns several processor cycles later, it might be released (signalled).

Answer (score 3):

Don't think of mutex objects as being signaled or non-signaled.  Instead, think about them as being owned or unowned.

The second parameter in the call below says that the mutex is initially unowned.

```
HANDLE hmutex= CreateMutex(NULL,FALSE,"");
```

The very first time the call below is made, the calling thread will take ownership of the mutex.  If another thread makes the same call *while the mutex is owned by the first thread*, the return value will be `WAIT_TIMEOUT` (258 decimal, 102 hex).

```
DWORD dw = WaitForSingleObject(hmutex,0);
```

Here are some guidelines to follow.  Use mutexes if you need to restrict access to a resource shared by multiple processes.  If you are restricting access to a resource within a single process, use [CRITICAL_SECTION](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682530%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) instead.  If you are wanting an object that one thread can use to signal another thread, use [events](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682655%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: and then there were semaphores.  And condition variables.